# Raising both sides of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Quickie: say you have the expression;

$$\frac{d\ln(x)}{d\ln(y)} = z$$

Is it legit to raise both sides by $e$ so it becomes

*original question*

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = e^z$$

*edited because I forgot about math*

$$ e^{\left( \dfrac{d \ln x}{d \ln y}\right)} = e^z$$

Comment: What is your definition of the expression $d\ln x/d\ln y$?

Comment: It is legit to raise both sides by $e$ so that it becomes $e^ { \frac { d\, \ln x} { d \, \ln y} } = e^z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is pure formality, I've never seen such a notation. But if want to follow all rules of differentiation and etc., you could have done this
$$
d \ln x = \frac {dx}x \\
d \ln y = \frac {dy}y \\
\frac {d \ln x}{d \ln y} = \frac {y\,dx}{x\,dy} = z \\
\frac {dx}{dy} = z\frac xy
$$

Comment: OK so this is cool. Not to sound too stupid (though I think I blew that in my original post) but why is $d\ln x = \dfrac{dx}{x}$?

Comment: Denote $f = \ln x$, so its derivative $f' = \frac {df}{dx} = \frac 1x$, from which you can find $df = \frac {dx}x$, and just recall that $df = d\ln x$. just like Sami put in his answer.

Comment: Now that you've written it it seems trivial, but this is a major "penny drop" moment for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex no problem.

Answer (score 2):

We have $df(x)=f'(x)dx$ so
$$z=\frac{d\ln x}{d\ln y}=\frac{y\,dx}{x\,dy}$$
hence
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=z\frac{x}{y}.$$